# How can I examine multiple elements for the existence of a class in Vue?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a Vue app that is a complicated form with lots of on and off rules depending on choices that are made.
I've done this by creating components in sections.
Before the submit button (in the last section) is enabled, I want to check that everything that can be filled in, is.
I have a class that I update when an element has been filled in. need-to-fill is the class in place until some data has been put into the field or component

```
<template>
  <div>
  <div>
        <label class="block">
          <span :class="[Boolean(loadFormDate) ? 'bg-blue-lighter': 'need-to-fill']"><strong>Date:</strong></span>
          <datepicker
            placeholder="Select Date"
            @selected="commitDate('formDate', $event)"
            :value="loadFormDate" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1">
        <label class="block">
          <span  :class="[Boolean(staffID) ? 'bg-blue-lighter': 'need-to-fill','w-full']"><strong>Staff ID:</strong></span>
          <input class="block" placeholder="Staff ID"
                 @input="commitField('staffID', $event.target.value)"
                 :value="staffID"
          />
        </label>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I would like to search through all elements to see that "need-to-fill" does not exists in any element and if it does not, to enable the submit button.

Answer (score 3):

I'll presume you set desired class `'need-to-fill'` correctly already.
Create `disabled` variable which determines whether button is disabled or not:

```
data: () => ({
  disabled: true,
}),
```

And set the indicator on button, and reference on the form element `ref="form"`:

```
<form ref="form">
  // ...
  <button :disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note: it doesn't have to be `form`, it can be `div` or whatever, as long as it contains all of your form inputs.

Create function that checks if any descendant of your form element contains desired class:

```
const descendantContainsClass = (el, className) => {
  let elements = Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('*'))
  let hasClass = false
  for(let el of elements) {
    if(el.classList.contains(className)) {
      hasClass = true
      break;
    }
  }
  return hasClass
}
```

Depends how you store form data (i.e. your input v-model values) create a watcher (or watchers) and call the function each time the data changes:

```
watch: {
    form: {
      deep: true,
      handler(v) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          // we pass form element, and desired class to check against
          this.disabled = descendantContainsClass(this.$refs.form.$el, 'need-to-fill')
      })
    }
  }
},
```

Depending on your form, you might not need watcher, but just call the function (same thing that is in `handler`) after for example `change` or `input` events.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the solution in a different way. I see you have **loadFormDate** and **staffID** variables inside **data()** . So instead of checking class names, you can check those two variables if they are empty or not in a **computed property** after that you can make the button disabled or enabled.

```js
data() {
  return {
    loadFormDate: '',
    staffID: '',
...

computed: {
   isNotFilled() {
     this.loadFormDate !== '' && this.staffID !== '' ? return false : return true           
   }

...

<template>
  <button :disabled="isNotFilled">
```

Comment: That would work fine if this was the only template.  But there are 6 templates and many more entry inputs than are in the example. I need to be able to drill down from the top component to see into all of the other included components

Comment: If you are dealing with large forms I think you need to use a 3rd party packages like v-validate, maybe it will decrease the line of code for form validations. But I don't locating empty inputs by looking into the class names is a good idea. I recommend you checking https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/ library. Using this library does not let you press send button if an input is invalid or empty.

Comment: Appreciate your thoughts, but this is not a "normal" form. The validation rules change based on selections. While I could use a validation package, or could build validation rules in the state source (I'm using vuex), I want to do it the way that I've asked in the question.